# Rolling forecast with xreg and re-estimation

Tags: regression, forecasting, cross-validation, arima

I tried implementing xreg into my rolling forecast with re-estimation.
Unfortunately I'm facing issues with the length of xreg.

```
# sample data  
sample <- ts(rnorm(100, mean = 1000, sd=7), start = c(2012,1), end = c(2019,12), frequency = 12)
external <- ts(mtcars, start = c(2012,1), end = c(2019,12), frequency = 12)

#Define h --> One-step ahead (for a start, later to be increased)
h <- 1
#specify length to forecast
test  <- window(sample, start = c(2018,01), end = c(2019,12), frequency = 12)
n <- length(test) - h + 1
#provide total length of regressors available
total_xreg <- ts(external[,c(1,2,3)], start = c(2012,1), end= c(2019,12), frequency = 12)

#create empty matrix
fcmatx <- matrix(0, nrow=n, ncol=h)

# create loop
for(i in 1:n)
{  
# x is the target variable, provide training data 
  x <- window(sample, end= c(2017,12) + (i-1)/12)
# provide xregs for training data
  xregs <- window(total_xreg, end = c(2017,12) + (i-1)/12)
# provide new xregs for forecasting, assuming that xreg is available for the forecasting period
  xregs2 <- window(total_xreg, start = c(2018,1) + (i-1)/12
# limit xregs2 to show only the first line since we are only forecasting 1 step in advance
 xregs3 <- xregs2[1,]
# create auto.arima model
  refit.multirex <- auto.arima(x, xreg = xregs)
# forecast using regressors
  fcmatx[i,] <- forecast(refit.multirex, 
                         h=h, 
                         xreg = xregs3
                         )$mean
}
fcmattsx <- ts(fcmatx, start = c(2018,1), frequency = 12)
```

This results in the following error:

```
Error in forecast.forecast_ARIMA(refit.multirex, h = h, xreg = xregs3) : 
  Number of regressors does not match fitted model
```

h is length 1 and xregs is length 3 because I'm filling in 3 variables but they are all only for one period of time. I tried various adjustments but cannot get it right.

Comment: Your code is not runnable. Please edit your post to provide a [Minimal (!) Working (!) Example](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffsb&q=minimal+working+example+in+R&ia=web).

Comment: I replaced the cody with sample data, now it should be runnable @StephanKolassa, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following line

```
xregs3 <- xregs2[1,]
```

returns a vector rather than a matrix. This is the default behaviour in R when you extract a single column or row from a matrix. Change it to

```
xregs3 <- xregs2[1,,drop=FALSE]
```

to keep the matrix structure (1x3). Then the `forecast()` function will not return an error.

You will get a different error when `i=23` because then you have `start` after `end` when creating `xregs2`.

Comment: Thank you for helping out with the matrix structure. I changed this and also replaced the regressors with a longer ts:
`total_xreg <- ts(external[,c(1,2,3)], start = c(2012,1), end = c(2020,5), frequency = 12)`. Now it runs smoothly, thank you!

Comment: @robjhyndman Is there a chance to print out the selected ARIMA order at each iteration to show how the model selection changes?

Comment: as.character(refit.multirex) will print out the ARIMA model.